# Plot data against time

Tags: r, date, vector, plot

I'm trying to plot vector a, which contains returns on a stock over nearly 15 years (about 5000 values in total), against vector b, my time vector.

```
a = (0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.5,...,0.2)
b = ("2001-07-23",...,"2015-12-31")
```

I transformed both vectors into factors, both have the same length obviously.

Comment: Why did you transform them into factors?

Comment: I first had to extract the two vector out of a large dataframe. Then I transformed the date values from YYYYMMDD into "YYYY-MM-DD", without transforming into factor it did not work out.

Comment: Does `plot(b, a)` not work?

Comment: Mh, it does work actually, it's just the y-axis is kinda messed up. a values lie between 0 and 1, the y-axis goes from 0 to 5. That's what I could try to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with:

- `lubridate` to parse your dates
- `ggplot2` to build the graph
- `dplyr` for pretty syntax

Here's the code:

```
a <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15)
b <- c("2001-07-23", "2001-07-24", "2001-07-25", "2001-07-26")

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(dates = as_date(b),
                 metric = a)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=dates, y=metric)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Really worked fine, thing is, how do I change the min/max of the y-axis? Used the code on my actual data, y-axis is kinda messed up, I want to scale it down

Comment: @mesjoga1311 Add this code after `geom_col` to set the y-axis min/max: `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 10))`. (in this example min is -1 and max is 10)